# DIV transparency and inheritance CSS DIV background has image, DIV outer has white background, DIV inner is a transparent window

Tags: html, css

See http://jsfiddle.net/mshaffer/g9q0p0nk/2/

CSS

```
div#bg {
  background-image: url(http://static4.grsites.com/archive/textures/red/red001.jpg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

div#outer {
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}


div#inner {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 90px;
  border: solid 2px yellow;
  color: yellow;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="bg">
<div id="outer">
<div id="inner">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is a hack, derivation from another question.

div#bg has an image

div#outer has a background of white (e.g., a modal)

div#inner has a background of transparent, border yellow.

With the transparency, I want to see the background image overriding the white from the previous layer...

white I guess could be a border generated as a psuedo layer using jquery.  However, I am hoping there is a CSS3 solution.

Comment: Why not just set the background-image on the `inner` element? http://jsfiddle.net/g9q0p0nk/3/

Comment: I am building a cropping tool... https://github.com/MonteShaffer/cropMe and this solution is not possible...  See http://md5.mshaffer.com/crop-me/_play/ for a work-in-progress.

Comment: What transparency? All divs are transparent until you apply a background. You can't cut holes in divs without a `mask-image` and that's webkit only.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for "cutting holes" through a div ...

Answer (score 1):

The white div has to be transparent. It's easiest to have a very big, white box-shadow:

http://jsfiddle.net/g9q0p0nk/5/

```css
div#bg {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("http://static4.grsites.com/archive/textures/red/red001.jpg");
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div#outer {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3000px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 38px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

div#inner {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 2px yellow;
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
    <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not the solution I am looking for.  Each div #bg, #outer, #inner will have a different jquery action bound to it ... $("#bg").bind(...)

Comment: Now there are two divs, although this isn't necessary.

Comment: I have a need for three bindings ... so I need three divs... "isn't necessary" is a bit of a leap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing something, but have you tried:

```
div#outer {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border:11px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned, I could do some dynamic "border" function like this in jquery.  I am hoping for a CSS solution.

Comment: And, if I have such a large border, I don't have the ability to "bind" and event handler to it.  For the #inner, I want to have one bind event, and for the #outer I want a different bind event.

Answer (score 0):

@Paulie_D is probably right, cutting a hole into the universe probably doesn't work.

http://md5.mshaffer.com/crop-me/_play/

My solution is to have

```
<div id="transparent">
    <div id="bg">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="modal">
    <div class="pseudo-modal">
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>       
    </div>
    <div class="view-window">
    </div>
</div>
```

with a bunch of jquery handling.

The **#modal** gets placed over the top of the **#transparent** blocking any binding methods attached to those elements.

When *"dragStarts"*, the **#modal** becomes transparent, and **.psuedo-modal** elements get the **#modal** color/opacity.  As the *drag occurs*, the four bounding elements are adjusted to give the appearance of the view window.

This enables *"dragStop"* to bind different events to **.psuedo-modal** elements and the **.view-window**

Sorry, trying to get the plugin down, I won't detach a small working example to jsfiddle at this time.  The link above works, and shows the how, with a bit more complication.